# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen on http-parser 1.2.3

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler

I've updated my macOS to Big Sur 11.3.1 and reinstall the xcode command. When I run `bundle install` for my Gemfile (I didn't use rail), it occurs error when install the `gem http-parser 1.2.3`.

Then it occurs the error:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/relaxlalalala/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/3.0.0/http-parser-1.2.3/gem.build_complete
```

I've tried

```
sudo chown -R relaxlalalala .rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/3.0.0/http-parser-1.2.3/gem.build_complete
```

but it said

```
chown: .rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/3.0.0/http-parser-1.2.3/gem.build_complete: No such file or directory
```

How can I get the folder permission or resolve the `gem.build_complete` problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What should the permissions be?

Looking at my own rbenv installation,

- I own all files under `~/.rbenv`, and
- directories under `~/.rbenv` are `drwxr-xr-x` (755) and
- files are either `-rw-rw-r--` (664) or
- `-rwxrwxr-x` (775), if they are meant to be executable.

### Recommendation

Just reinstall everything :)

```
rbenv uninstall 3.0.1
rbenv install 3.0.1
bundle install
```